# Forms not clearing themselves of default value?

Tags: css, forms, html, default-value

I notice this as a frequent problem on *many* wbesites, even those of large corporations, so as a web developer applying for jobs, I think, *I should know how to fix this.*

Basically, for example, a username field will say "Username" until you click it to type in your username, at which time it should clear itself of the text "Username." But in most cases, it doesn't, and you end up typing in the middle of that pre-existing text.

I've looked this up, and the best solution I found was a 30+ line set of Javascript functions which did exactly what you'd expect: set up a system that clears the default value away when a user clicks on the field, and also puts it back when they click away so long as they hadn't entered anything.

But that's not really what I was looking for, because I already knew how to do that.

I feel like by now, with HTML5 and all, there should be a simpler fix to this. And not just a reduction of the JavaScript to a shorter jQuery script. I mean more of an embedded, inherent fix.

Does anyone know of any ways to stop this phenomenon from happening?

Comment: Are you referring to the placeholder text? Please post some code.

Comment: Use placeholder instead of value maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use HTML5 `placeholder attribute`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Whatever" />
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4XPee/)

Cross Browser Info :
Some Firefox versions clear the placeholder text on click of text box and Chrome clears it after the user starts typing, but later version of Firefox acts like chrome, it clears the placeholder text as the user starts typing in the input box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML5 placeholder attribute http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers now support the placeholder attribute for forms, which let you do just what your asking

Check out
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text
For a article using modenizr for cross browser compatibility

Answer (score 0):

just use the HTML5 placeholder attribute.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
```

This will obviosuly not be completely cross browser compatible so for that you will still need the old Javascript / jQuery fixes.